# Unable to Scale Down Messages when using JGroups

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have created ActiveMQ Artemis (v2.29.0) Clusters using JGroups and have enabled HA Policy as Scale Down using discovery groups, but it is failing.

broker.xml

```xml
      <acceptors>
         <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true;supportAdvisory=false;suppressInternalManagementObjects=false</acceptor>
      </acceptors>

      <connectors>
         <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616</connector>
      </connectors>


      <broadcast-groups>
         <broadcast-group name="my-broadcast-group">
            <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
            <jgroups-file>jgroup-file-ping.xml</jgroups-file>
            <jgroups-channel>active_broadcast_channel</jgroups-channel>
            <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
         </broadcast-group>
      </broadcast-groups>

      <discovery-groups>
         <discovery-group name="my-discovery-group">
            <jgroups-file>jgroup-file-ping.xml</jgroups-file>
            <jgroups-channel>active_broadcast_channel</jgroups-channel>
            <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
         </discovery-group>
      </discovery-groups>

      <cluster-connections>
         <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
            <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
            <retry-interval>2000</retry-interval>
            <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
            <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
            <max-hops>1</max-hops>
            <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="my-discovery-group"/>
         </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>

      <ha-policy>
         <live-only>
            <scale-down>
               <enabled>true</enabled>
               <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="my-discovery-group"/>
            </scale-down>
         </live-only>
      </ha-policy>
```

jgroup-file-ping.xml

```xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="urn:org:jgroups"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups http://www.jgroups.org/schema/jgroups.xsd">
    <TCP bind_addr="${jgroups.bind_addr:site_local}"
         bind_port="${jgroups.bind_port:7800}"
         external_addr="${jgroups.external_addr}"
         external_port="${jgroups.external_port}"
         thread_pool.min_threads="0"
         thread_pool.max_threads="200"
         thread_pool.keep_alive_time="30000"/>
    <RED/>

    <!-- a location that can be found by both server's running -->
    <FILE_PING location="../../file.ping.dir"/>
    <MERGE3  min_interval="10000"
             max_interval="30000"/>
    <FD_SOCK2/>
    <FD_ALL3 timeout="40000" interval="5000" />
    <VERIFY_SUSPECT2 timeout="1500"  />
    <BARRIER />
    <pbcast.NAKACK2 use_mcast_xmit="false" />
    <UNICAST3 />
    <pbcast.STABLE desired_avg_gossip="50000"
                   max_bytes="4M"/>
    <pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="true" join_timeout="2000"/>
    <UFC max_credits="2M"
         min_threshold="0.4"/>
    <MFC max_credits="2M"
         min_threshold="0.4"/>
    <FRAG2 frag_size="60K"  />
    <!--RSVP resend_interval="2000" timeout="10000"/-->
    <pbcast.STATE_TRANSFER/>
</config>
```

For the other broker, the configuration is same except for the ports.
When I am stopping the broker with the command `artemis stop`, scale downs fail.

I checked using connectors, it is working.

```
2023-07-31 17:01:15,202 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221029: stopped bridge $.artemis.internal.sf.my-cluster.eef60017-2f81-11ee-adb4-ea6113f38d3a
2023-07-31 17:01:15,295 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222181: Unable to scaleDown messages
org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQInternalErrorException: AMQ219004: Failed to initialise session factory
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.initialize(ServerLocatorImpl.java:277) ~[artemis-core-client-2.29.0.jar:2.29.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:671) ~[artemis-core-client-2.29.0.jar:2.29.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.connect(ServerLocatorImpl.java:570) ~[artemis-core-client-2.29.0.jar:2.29.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.connect(ServerLocatorImpl.java:549) ~[artemis-core-client-2.29.0.jar:2.29.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.LiveNodeLocator.connectToCluster(LiveNodeLocator.java:85) ~[artemis-server-2.29.0.jar:2.29.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.LiveOnlyActivation.connectToScaleDownTarget(LiveOnlyActivation.java:148) [artemis-server-2.29.0.jar:2.29.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.LiveOnlyActivation.freezeConnections(LiveOnlyActivation.java:116) [artemis-server-2.29.0.jar:2.29.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.freezeConnections(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:1550) [artemis-server-2.29.0.jar:2.29.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.stop(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:1324) [artemis-server-2.29.0.jar:2.29.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.stop(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:1243) [artemis-server-2.29.0.jar:2.29.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.stop(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:1227) [artemis-server-2.29.0.jar:2.29.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.stop(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:1038) [artemis-server-2.29.0.jar:2.29.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.FileBroker.stop(FileBroker.java:94) [artemis-cli-2.29.0.jar:2.29.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.commands.Run.stop(Run.java:222) [artemis-cli-2.29.0.jar:2.29.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.commands.Run$2.run(Run.java:196) [artemis-cli-2.29.0.jar:2.29.0]
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:566) [?:?]
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:516) [?:?]
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQInternalErrorException: channel is closed
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.startDiscovery(ServerLocatorImpl.java:291) ~[artemis-core-client-2.29.0.jar:2.29.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.initialize(ServerLocatorImpl.java:273) ~[artemis-core-client-2.29.0.jar:2.29.0]
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: channel is closed
        at org.jgroups.JChannel.checkClosed(JChannel.java:983) ~[jgroups-5.2.0.Final.jar:5.2.0.Final]
        at org.jgroups.JChannel._preConnect(JChannel.java:792) ~[jgroups-5.2.0.Final.jar:5.2.0.Final]
        at org.jgroups.JChannel.connect(JChannel.java:322) ~[jgroups-5.2.0.Final.jar:5.2.0.Final]
        at org.jgroups.JChannel.connect(JChannel.java:316) ~[jgroups-5.2.0.Final.jar:5.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.jgroups.JChannelWrapper.connect(JChannelWrapper.java:127) ~[artemis-core-client-2.29.0.jar:2.29.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.JGroupsBroadcastEndpoint.internalOpen(JGroupsBroadcastEndpoint.java:121) ~[artemis-core-client-2.29.0.jar:2.29.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.JGroupsBroadcastEndpoint.openClient(JGroupsBroadcastEndpoint.java:99) ~[artemis-core-client-2.29.0.jar:2.29.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.cluster.DiscoveryGroup.start(DiscoveryGroup.java:113) ~[artemis-core-client-2.29.0.jar:2.29.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.startDiscovery(ServerLocatorImpl.java:289) ~[artemis-core-client-2.29.0.jar:2.29.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.initialize(ServerLocatorImpl.java:273) ~[artemis-core-client-2.29.0.jar:2.29.0]
        ... 16 more
2023-07-31 17:01:15,485 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241005: Stopping embedded web server
2023-07-31 17:01:15,497 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.AuthenticationFilter] Destroying hawtio authentication filter
2023-07-31 17:01:15,499 INFO  [io.hawt.HawtioContextListener] Destroying hawtio services
2023-07-31 17:01:15,530 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.plugin.PluginContextListener] Destroyed artemis-plugin plugin
2023-07-31 17:01:15,542 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.branding.PluginContextListener] Destroyed activemq-branding plugin
2023-07-31 17:01:15,568 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241006: Stopped embedded web server
2023-07-31 17:01:15,570 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221002: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 2.29.0 [2df21bb4-24c6-11ee-accf-0adf5b5db694] stopped, uptime 13.875 seconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3831). I've sent [a PR](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/pull/4739) so it should be fixed in the next release of ActiveMQ Artemis.