# Broker Connection is creating infinite loop when using redistribution-delay

Tags: activemq-artemis

As scale-down is not working for me on AKS I am thinking of a workaround -

I have 2 brokers which are in a cluster. I have configured `broker connection` in one of the broker let's say `broker2`. The broker connection looks -

```xml
      <broker-connections>
         <amqp-connection uri="tcp://localhost:61617" name="scale-down" user="artemis" password="artemis" auto-start="false">
            <sender address-match="#"/>
         </amqp-connection>
      </broker-connections>
```

When I want to stop the `broker2`, I start the `broker-connection`, wait for a few seconds and then stop the broker. (both using curl command)
This scenario is working fine when **not using** `redistribution-delay` under `address-settings`. But when using `redistribution-delay`, messages are stuck in an infinite loop between the `broker1` and `broker2`

I want some suggestions on how to achieve this, or if there is a better workaround.

Is there a way I can stop the ClusterConnection Bridge before I enable BrokerConnection?

Comment: Why isn't scale-down working for you?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76803267/unable-to-scale-down-messages-when-using-jgroups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop the cluster connection (which will stop the corresponding bridge) by using the `stop` operation on the corresponding [`ClusterConnectionControl`](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/ClusterConnectionControl.html). You can do this via any management interface (e.g. web console, HTTP via Jolokia, JMX, etc.).

You can also manually trigger scale-down by using the [`scaleDown` operation of the `ActiveMQServerControl`](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/ActiveMQServerControl.html#scaleDown(java.lang.String)). There is one parameter you can pass. Here's the doc on that parameter:

> The connector to use to scale down, if not provided the first appropriate connector will be used

Again, you can invoke this operation via any management interface.